# Rownames for data.table in R for model.matrix

Tags: r, data.table, model.matrix

I have a `data.table` `DT` and I want to run `model.matrix` on it.  Each row has a string ID, which is stored in the `ID` column of `DT`.  When I run `model.matrix` on `DT`, my formula excludes the `ID` column.  The problem is, `model.matrix` drops some rows because of NAs.  If I set the rownames of `DT` to the `ID` column, before calling `model.matrix`, then the final model matrix has rownames, and I'm all set.  Otherwise, I can't figure out what rows I end up with.  I'm setting the rownames with `rownames(DT) = DT$ID`.  However, when I try to add a new column to `DT`, I get a complaint about

> "Invalid .internal.selfref detected . . . At an earlier point, this
>   data.table has been copied by R."

So I'm wondering

1. Is there a better way to set rownames for a `data.table`
2. Is there a better approach to solving this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

Firstly, it is a feature of a `data.table` that they do not have a `rownames`, instead they have `key`s which are far more powerful. See [this great vignette](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-intro.pdf).

But, it isn't the end of the world. `model.matrix` returns sensible rownames when you pass it a `data.table`

For example

```
A <- data.table(ID = 1:5, x = c(NA, 1:4), y = c(4:2,NA,3))

mm <- model.matrix( ~ x + y, A)

rownames(mm)

## [1] "2" "3" "5"
```

So rows 2,3 and 5 are those included in the model.matrix.

Now, you can add this sequence as a column to `A`. This will be useful if you then set the key to something else (thereby losing the original order)

```
A[, rowid := seq_len(nrow(A)]
```

You might consider making it character (like the rownames of `mm`)) but it won't really matter (as you can just as easily convert  `rownames(mm)` to numeric when you need to reference.

As to the warning that `data.table` gives, if you read the next sentence

> Avoid key<-, names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: setkey(), setnames() and setattr()

`rownames` are an attribute `rownames<-` (internally at somepoint using the equivalent to `attr<-`)  will (possibly copy) in the same way.

The line from `` `row.names<-.data.frame` `` is

```
attr(x, "row.names") <- value
```

That being said, `data.tables` don't have rownames, so there is no point setting them.

Comment: Thanks a lot -- sorry for my very-delayed followup.  So if I understand correctly, the key fact is that model.matrix puts the original row numbers as row names, and that's pretty much all I need.