# Loop over a data.table rows with condition

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data.table that holds ids and locations. for example, here is it with one row in it:
(it has col and row names, don't know if it matters)

```
locations<-data.table(c(11,12),c(-159.58,0.2),c(21.901,22.221))
colnames(locations)<-c("id","location_lon","location_lat")
rownames(locations)<-c("1","2")
```

I then want to iterate over the rows and compare them to another point (with lat,lon).
In a for loop it works:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(locations)) {
    loc <- locations[i,]
    dist <- gdist(-159.5801, 21.901, loc$location_lon, loc$location_lat, units="m")
    if(dist <= 50) {
        return (loc)
    }
    return (NULL)
}
```

and returns:

> id location_lon location_lat
>
> 1: 11      -159.58       21.901

but I want to use apply.
The following code fails to run:

```
dists <- apply(locations,1,function(x) if (50 - gdist(-159.5801, 21.901, x$location_lon, x$location_lat, units="m")>=0) x else NULL)
```

with `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` error. Changing to reference by location (`x[2],x[3]`) isn't enough to fix this, I get

```
Error in if (radius - gdist(lon, lat, x[2], x[3], units = "m") >= 0) x else NULL : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

This is because the data.table is converted to matrix, and the coordinates are treated as text instead of numbers.
Is there a way to overcome this? The solution needs to be efficient (I want to run this check for >1,000,000 different coordinates). Changing the data structure of the locations table is possible if needed.

Comment: I added this an example for a working code. In the real loop everything is passed as variables and the rowname is automatically generated.

Comment: Where the `gdist` function comes from?

Comment: Can you create a data set with more than one row and provide your desired output? I also don't see a reason whatsoever to use `data.table` if all you do are `for` loops and `apply` loops without using any built in `data.table` features

Comment: `dist` comes from the `Imap` package

Comment: Don't know the package. Is `gdist` vectorized? If so, you don't need any loop. If not, use any of the `dist*` functions from `geosphere`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No loops are required, just use `data.table` as intended. If all you want to see are the rows that within 50 meters from the desired location, all you have to do is

```
locations[, if (gdist(-159.58, 21.901, location_lon, location_lat, units="m") <= 50) .SD, id]
##    id location_lon location_lat
## 1: 11      -159.58       21.901
```

Here we are iterating by the `id` column within the `locations` data set itself and checking if each `id` is within 50 meters from `-159.58, 21.901`. If so, we are calling `.SD` which is basically the data set itself for that specific `id`.

---

As a side note, `data.table` doesn't have `row.names`, so there is no need of specifiying them, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977745/rownames-for-data-table-in-r-for-model-matrix), for example